# Mask user input like password on vscode extension configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing vscode extension in which I need to take user input like username and password, I am unable to find input type password in vscode docs, input masking is supported in vscode api ?

[image: password]

Comment: all settings are stored in clear text, what is the use to mask them in the GUI

Comment: @rioV8 That should disuade shoulder-surfing people from seeing the password, even though it's stored in clear text. It's a good practice to mask password fields regardless of what happens to them afterwards.

Comment: The password should not be stored in the settings at all. It's not a setting/configuration!

Comment: Not all user inputs are stored in settings - they may be used to set up a remote connection, and discarded.

There must be some way to mask user inputs?

Answer (score 3):

The VS Code Settings are not the right place to store credentials. Instead, use `vscode.SecretStorage`, e.g. with a VS Code Command:

```js
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const secretStorage: vscode.SecretStorage = context.secrets;

  vscode.commands.registerCommand('mynotebook.setPassword', async () => {
    const passwordInput: string = await vscode.window.showInputBox({
      password: true, 
      title: "Password"
    }) ?? '';
    
    secretStorage.store("server_password", passwordInput);
  })

  ...
}
```

If you want the newly created command to be easily accessible from the Settings, use a link in `package.json`:

```json
"server.password": {
  "type": "null",
  "scope": "application",
  "markdownDescription": "[Set Password](mynotebook.setPassword)"
}
```

Comment: The `markdownDescription` value shall be `[Set Password](command:mynotebook.setPassword)` instead?